# Probability question - defected screws

Tags: probability

I have this question:

A factory has 100 screws. $60\%$ of them are from manufacturer A and the rest from manufacturer B. $10\%$ of the screws of manufacturer A are defected, and $5\%$ of the screws of manufacturer B are defected. 
in an interval of 10 days a worker is checking one screw each day. What is the probability that the worker will encounter at most 1 defective screw? Each day, The worker start with 100 screws (with return).

I did a probability tree, and came up with 0.08 as the probability to be defected. so the probability not to be defected is $1-0.08 = 0.92$. now I did multiplication of $P(X\text{ is defected}): P(X=0) + P(X=1)$.
I used the binomial distribution formula to calculate it, but I can't get to the right answer for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How did you arrive at 0.062?

Comment: I Did it again now (0.6*0.1)+(0.4*0.05), I got 0.08. I think this is better?

Comment: If you want the P of at most 1 screw defective,  does it make a difference if that screw came from company A or company B? Could it be that all 100 screws are mixed? It changes the answer,  but it's not clear from the question

Comment: It is mixed and each day, the worker checks all the 100 screws (it's with return).

Comment: If it is all mixed then the way I read it is that there are 100 screws of which 15 are defective. With return, it's Binomial distribution. $P(X=0)+P(X=1)$. If each day a screw is checked for 10 days,  n=10, p=0.15

Comment: If the worker checks all 100 screws he will find all 15 defect screws with probability 1. And this will happen every 10 days. I assume that nothing happens to screws during these 10 days.

Comment: I'm sorry I updated it for clarification. Each day there are 100 screws. Each day the worker checks one screw.

Comment: @user Look up a few comments where the OP says, "It's with return." But he's just edited the question

Comment: @saulspatz I see that OP has problems with formulating his question unambiguously.

Comment: Please mention in your question the fact that the worker put the screw back after checking it.

Comment: @user, Thanks and sorry, I indicated all the information now.

Comment: I don't understand where you get $.08$.  there are $15$ defective screws out of $100$.  The probability that the worker picks a defective screw is $.15.$

Comment: @saulspatz I thought at first that it includes Conditional probability, meaning what is the probability to be defective given manufacturer A or B, but I guess that was not the trick here.

Comment: Didn't the question used to say $10$ screws and $5$ screws, without the percent signs?

Comment: @saulspatz  No, It's with the percents, probably didn't displayed right a first because of formatting. so if it's prevents I guess the  answer is the same just with 8 screws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the checked screw is defect is $0.6\cdot0.1+0.4\cdot0.05=0.08$. Therefore the probability that at most one defect screw will be found in 10 trials is
$$0.92^{10}+10\times 0.92^9\times 0.08.$$

Comment: See edit: The $\%$ symbols were not displayed due to formatting errors.

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected the answer.